# Why is there no "Autocomplete of code /intellisense" when writing code using Python window in ArcGIS Pro 2.7?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-window

In the process of using ArcGIS Pro 2.7, I need to enter the code in Python window. Under normal circumstances, it should be possible to automatically prompt related tools and functions when entering letters.
[image]

However, in my environment, Windows 10, ArcGIS Pro 2.7.0, enter letters in Python window without any prompt.

[image: the situation of my software: there is no prompt]

I can drag and drop tools from the toolbox, or I can display code in the python window, but there is no prompt for the following parameters.
[image]

I have tried to repair and reinstall the software, but it is still unresolved.
I would like to ask if anyone else has a similar situation and how to solve it.

It always feels that there should be related settings, or registry keys, to control this part.

In addition, if PyCharm or VSCode is used, the prompt can be obtained normally. But I want to learn related functions in ArcGIS Pro, so I want to solve this problem.

Comment: It's a Python console, not an IDE.

Comment: Python window : https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/python-window.htm